# how to read text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want to read text file using batch script,
i have a log file which contain some data and i want to read BUILD number from that text file and display.

Example : Build:2016.17.05_0872

is there any way to read like this ?

```
@echo off
findstr /m "Build" C:\Users\admin.DESKTOP-CUDDLMA\Desktop\a.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
 echo Build found
)

@pause
```

this what i have done so far , it is just searching that word in file.

Comment: You don't describe your environment. Please read what a [mcve] is. [SO] isn't a script writing service, so show what code you already have and where you got stuck.

Comment: pls check edited question  with code

Comment: try without `/m`. See `for /?` what `/m` does.

Comment: Has this really got anything to do with the tag spring-batch?

Comment: okay got it, but i want read that line after Build word. its reading entire line from beginning

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option based upon my best guess from the limited information you have provided:

I'm guessing your `FileName.txt` looks a little like this:

```
This is the first line
Name:MyProject Build:2016.17.05_0872 Author:Jacob
There are other words on this line
```

…and you want as output this:

```
2016.17.05_0872
```

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "srcFile=FileName.txt"
Set "srcTerm=Build:"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr/LIC:"%srcTerm%" "%srcFile%" 2^>Nul') Do (
    Set "_=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F %%B In ("!_:*%srcTerm%=!") Do Echo=%%B
    EndLocal)

Timeout -1
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

*Just change the file name on line 4 to match the actual text file name you are searching.*

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, so I will try to complete it.

If you have a text file like this one:

```
First line
Build:2016.17.05_0872
Other line
```

... and you want as output this line:

```
2016.17.05_0872
```

... then this Batch file solves your problem:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "Build" textFile.txt') do echo %%a
```

Comment: Did you tested it _with the 3-lines file I posted above_? Note that you did NOT provided any example input file... **`:(`**

Answer (score -2):

In Windows ("batch" sounds like Windows), you would use:

```
find /I "build" *.log
```

Comment: sorry to say but i am new to this technology can u pls write full code ?

Comment: In Windows, start a command prompt - Win-R, cmd, Enter. Then type the commands given in the folder where the log file resides. Or specify the filename with full path.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply do this using grep

```
grep "BUILD" filename.txt
```

Comment: Windows does not natively come with grep. This answer is useless.

Comment: sorry to say but i am new to this technology can u pls write full code ?

Comment: @Resu: that IS full code. But Unix-code. Translated to the windows-world: `find /i "Build:" filename.txt`

Comment: its searching for all the BUILD word